# Inject multiple beans of the same type and automatically select between them based on generic type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have two (more in the future) implementations of `ImportantService` – `VeryImportantService` and `LessImportantService`:

```
public interface ImportantService<T extends ImportantRequest> {}
```

```
@Service
public class VeryImportantService implements ImportantService<VeryImportantRequest> {}
```

```
@Service
public class LessImportantService implements ImportantService<LessImportantRequest> {}
```

And then I have a controller, in which I want to inject all of the implementations of `ImportantService`:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/important")
public class ImportantController<T extends ImportantRequest> {
    
    private final ImportantService<T> importantService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ImportantResponse> create(@RequestBody @Valid T request) {
        // very important code here
    }
}
```

Obviously, such king of injecting fails:

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'importantController' defined in file ...
...
Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

What I want is:

Inject all of the implementations of `ImportantService`, and then, based on the `T` automatically select required bean. I know I can add method to `ImportantService`, which returns the type that implementation works with and then inject `ImportantService` as `List<ImportantService> importantServices` and then filter like this:

```
importantServices.stream()
                 .filter(importantService -> importantService.getType().equals(request.getClass()))
                 .findFirst()
                 .ifPresent(importantService -> importantService.doImportantJob(request));
```

BUT! I have hundreds of services to refactor like this and I really don't want to write additional logic to controllers.

I know about `@Conditional` annotation and `Condition` interface, but AFAIK there's no way to make them do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not implement the [proxy pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/proxy_pattern.htm)?

example:

```
@Service
@Primary
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ImportantServiceProxy implements ImportantService<T extends ImportantRequest> {
   private final List<ImportantService> importantServices;
  
   private ImportantService getImportantService(ImportantRequest request){
       return this.importantServices.stream()
             .filter(importantService -> importantService.getType().equals(request.getClass()))
             .findFirst()
             .get();
   }
   
   public void doImportantJob(ImportantRequest request){
         this.getImportantService(request).doImportantJob(request);
   }
}
```

Then in your controller you can call the function without check the type.

```
 @RequiredArgsConstructor
 @RestController
 @RequestMapping("/api/important")
 public class ImportantController<T extends ImportantRequest> {

    private final ImportantService<T> importantService;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<ImportantResponse> create(@RequestBody @Valid T request) {
        importantService.doImportantJob(request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution looks good, the only problem is that I have to create N extra proxy services for N service interfaces :(

Comment: Still hope for "cleaner" solution

Comment: Oh, I missed the `@Primary` annotation and thought that I will have to be injecting proxy itself. Indeed, that's a pretty solution, I think I will go with that one, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

what you want is a list of beans which are of type ImportantService
so you have to declare a variable like this.

```
final List<ImportantService> importantServices;
demoController(List<ImportantService> importantServices) {
    this.importantServices = importantServices;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote at the end of my question. I know how to inject list of beans, what I don't know is if Spring can automatically understand which implementation he should use based on the type it's working with. I need to get rid of the last code example in controllers